# How to add line break to a string in Typescipt?

Tags: css, typescript, vue.js

I have a group of buttons that display months but they all show on one line/row and I want to put break at the end of June so it shows on two rows.How do I do that? I tried `June' + '\n'` and that didn't work and `<br>` that didn't work either. Updated with more code including from the Vue file and css.

Vue

```
    <common-subsection
        id="monthsSelected"
        headerTitle="Months">
        <common-forminputs-checkboxeswithvalidation
            rules="required|min:1"
            name="months"
            id="months"
            vid="months"
            :options="monthNames"
            v-model="months"
            buttons
            button-variant="primary"
            requiredDisplayName="Months"
        />
    </common-subsection>
```

Typescript

```
      months = [];
      monthNames = [
      'January',
      'February',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'August',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December',        
   ];
```

CSS

```
#months label.btn{
 margin: 0 0.25em 0 0;
 border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
 overflow: auto;
 float: left;
 height: 43px;
 width: auto;
 padding:0;
 background-color: #fff;
 color:#656565;
 min-width:150px;

  span{
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1em;
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   text-transform: capitalize;
   }

 &:hover{
    background: var(--secondary);
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

  &.active{
  background-color: #2e81ab;
  color: #fff;
  }

}
```

Updated code
Is that like this? If so that doesn't seem to work.

```
<common-subsection
   id="monthsSelected"
   headerTitle="Months"
   style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);">
   <common-forminputs-checkboxeswithvalidation
    rules="required|min:1"
    name="months"
    id="months"
    vid="months"
    :options="monthNames"
    v-model="months"
    buttons
    button-variant="primary"
    requiredDisplayName="Months"
 />
```

Comment: Please show the templates of the components, especially the part that renders the months and their styles.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all buttons inside tag with this styles:

```css
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
```

Comment: No.. I don't know vue but I think that months are inside ```common-forminputs-checkboxeswithvalidation``` so this is the component which should contains those styles.